# redirect_field_name DJANGO didn't work

Tags: python, django

I would redirect the user to "admin" page if he is superuser, else to normal "profile" but it didn't work

**urls.py**

```
 url(r'^user/login/', LoginUserView.as_view(), name='login'),
 url(r'^user/profile/', UpdateUserView.as_view(), name='profile'),
 url(r'^user/admin/$', UpdateAdminView.as_view(), name='admin'),
```

**views.py**

```
class LoginUserView(auth_views.LoginView):
    template_name = "Login/login.html"
    #TODO
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.request.user.is_superuser:
            self.redirect_field_name = reverse_lazy("admin")
        else:
            self.redirect_field_name = reverse_lazy("profile")
        return super(LoginUserView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting `redirect_field_name` isn't going to work - it is the name of a parameter, by default `'next'`, not the url to redirect to.

If you want to the success url, you should override `get_success_url`.

```
class LoginUserView(auth_views.LoginView):
    template_name = "Login/login.html"
    def get_success_url(self):
        url = self.get_redirect_url()
        if url:
            return url
        elif self.request.user.is_superuser:
            return reverse("admin")
        else:
            return reverse("profile")
```

The `get_redirect_url()` call at the beginning of the method means that the default behaviour that tries to use the redirect field will still work.

Answer (score -1):

"`e`" is missing in:

self.redirect_field_name = reverse_lazy("profile")